# Tasker profile with state doesn't activate

Tags: tasker

I'm trying to write a little program in Tasker, therefor I need a profile that is activated when a certain variable is set. However the profile does not activate, it does not go green. In the vars tab I can see that the variable is actually set. I know my Tasker installation is okay because I already have a profile that turns green when I have opened certain apps. I also tested the states "Display state on", "Wifi connected", "Battery Level". And even the state "Profile Active " doesnt work. The profile  is green but not the profile with state "Profile Active "! What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I do have such profiles runnning just fine. When you define the `context` for the profile, you need to set an **`event`** and not a `state` for a certain `variable set` or `variable clear`.

Comment: Yeah I just figured it out myself, profiles are not triggered by states but by events. Thanx. I am now stuck at changing the brightness level with Screen Filter. I can set a custom value in the program itself but not change it with Tasker. I use Plugin Action->Screen Filter->Configuration->x%.

Comment: Solved this problem too, the configuration has to be set when Screen Filter is off and then you can load it. Now my only problem is that I want to activate a profile when another profile is active combined with an event. With the event only the profile becomes active but not combined with the state Profile Active [Profile Name].