# No active profile issue for Tasker to Zooper widget

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, tasker

I am trying to get new mail notification from Tasker to Zooper widget, following the instructions given [here](http://www.theroundtraveller.net/2013/08/tasker-applications-unread-counts-with.html).
But Tasker says "*No Active profile*" and new mail updates are not coming until I run the "**play**" button in task.

I googled and come through similar question [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/44696/tasker-profile-with-state-doesnt-activate) and I make double check that I have indeed made an event for new mail.

The task is shown

[image: here] and [image: here].

If I manually push play button, everything is ok, but thats not what it supposed to, right?

Kindly show me what went wrong here.

I am using unrooted Nexus 5, kitkat-4.4.2 and Tasker and zooper pro are from playstore and updated, if those matters.

Comment: I've never used Zooper, but that sounds as if the task doesn't get triggerd. Have you just setup the task, or also a profile/event to trigger it? If so, maybe the app you're using doesn't correctly support this (i.e. doesn't inform on new messages).